# Swift .sheet modal doesn't dismiss after writing to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have my main view calling a subview as a .sheet modal in SwiftUI. There is a form in the sheet that the user fills out. A button at the bottom is supposed to write the data to Core Data and dismiss the modal. When I run the code without the Core Data write, it dismisses the modal without any issue. When I include the Core Data code, it writes it successfully but does not dismiss the modal. I've tried debugging it by incorporating @Environment as a pass through variable, using @Binding, and using various print statements to make sure the dismiss fires. I am not getting any errors, but the modal never disappears via the button.

Here is the relevant code fragment for the Main View:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {AddListItem(listName: "", favoriteFlag: false)
```

And here is the full code for the Sub View that shows the modal:

```
struct AddListItem: View {
@State var listName: String
@State var favoriteFlag: Bool
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("List Details")) {
                TextField("List Name", text: $listName)
                Toggle(isOn: $favoriteFlag) {
                    Text("Favorite?")
                }
            }
        }
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    let newItem = Item(context: self.viewContext)
                    newItem.timestamp = Date()

                    do {
                        try self.viewContext.save()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } catch {
                        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                        let nsError = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                    }
                }

                //self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Add Tasks to \(listName)")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Create New List")
    }

}
}
```

I've reviewed some similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but haven't been able to find a solution. I feel like I am missing something simple here... appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARGHH! I figured it out... thanks to this SO answer.[SwiftUI: Cannot dismiss sheet after creating CoreData object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081833/swiftui-cannot-dismiss-sheet-after-creating-coredata-object?rq=1)

I didn't see it initially. If it helps someone else, I made the mistake of having my .sheet attached to my ToolbarItem. It is supposed to be separate. Once I did that, no problems!